# Python error when converting map to list, monte carlo in functional programming

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

i need to rewrite a program which was counting area using monte carlo.
so im trying to use functional programming and i got an error when converting a map to a list:

here is a code

```
a=list(map((lambda x,y: math.sqrt((25/100)-(x*x))-y)(random.uniform(-1/2, 0),  random.uniform(0, 1/2)), [1]*1000))
```

and I get an error

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

(lambda is just a math function)

EDIT
I rewrote it like this:

```
a = list(map(lambda x, y: math.sqrt((25 / 100) - (x * x)) - y,
         list(map(lambda a, b: random.uniform(a, b), [-1/2]*1000, [0]*1000)), list(map(lambda a, b: random.uniform(a, b), [0]*1000, [1/2]*1000))))
```

Comment: Are you missing a comma in the map function? Between lambda function and iterable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:

```
a = list(map(lambda x, y: math.sqrt((25 / 100) - (x * x)) - y,
         [random.uniform(-1 / 2, 0) for _ in range(1000)], [random.uniform(0, 1 / 2) for _ in range(1000)]))
```

The error is caused by using map function incorrectly, instead of converting a map result into a list.

The first parameter of map should be a function, while in your case it's a float number calculated by calling a function:

```
(lambda x,y: math.sqrt((25/100)-(x*x))-y)(random.uniform(-1/2, 0),  random.uniform(0, 1/2))
```

Comment: I'm new into functional programming and my teacher doesn't let us use for i in range or any loop. Is for i in range correct?

Comment: @KaczkaDziwaczka  Here the for loop is used to generate random numbers. If you want to avoid any use of for loop, one way is to generate random numbers directly in the function: `a = list(map(lambda _: math.sqrt((25 / 100) - (random.uniform(-1 / 2, 0) ** 2)) - random.uniform(0, 1 / 2), ['foobar'] * 1000))`

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `map` should be a function / callable.

A `lambda` expression is a function literal (returns a function):

```
(lambda x,y: math.sqrt((25/100)-(x*x))-y)
```

but then you're immediately calling it, which returns a float:

```
(lambda x,y: math.sqrt((25/100)-(x*x))-y)(random.uniform(-1/2, 0)
```

You need to fix the expression to not call the lambda, proper formatting often reveals these issues, here's your expression better formatted:

```py
a=list(map(
    (lambda x,y: math.sqrt((25/100)-(x*x))-y)(
        random.uniform(-1/2, 0),  
        random.uniform(0, 1/2)
    ),
    [1]*1000
))
```

this rather obviously makes no sense.

You may want something like this:

```
a=list(map(
    lambda _: (
        (lambda x,y: math.sqrt((25/100)-(x*x))-y)(
            random.uniform(-1/2, 0),  
            random.uniform(0, 1/2)
        ),
    )
    [1]*1000
))
```

or

```py
a = list(map(
    lambda x,y: math.sqrt((25/100)-(x*x))-y),
    (random.uniform(-1/2, 0) for _ in range(1000)),
    (random.uniform(0, 1/2) for _ in range(1000)),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to see what you are doing, since everything is done in-line. So let's try unpack it to see what is going wrong

This is your lambda function:

```py
def foo(x, y):
    return math.sqrt(25/100)-x*x-y
```

You are calling this function in the point `random.uniform(-1/2, 0), random.uniform(0, 1/2)`. Then afterwards, you are applying a `map` - but you have already called your lambda, so it is no longer a function, but an evaluation in the aforementioned point (e.g. a `float`). Thus you get this error since `map` expects a function as its first argument

I assume what you are trying to do, is draw 1000 observations from your random variable, and apply those to your function. That you can do with the below code:

```py
def foo(x, y):
    return math.sqrt(25/100)-x*x-y
out = []
for i in range(1000):
    out.append(foo(random.uniform(-1/2, 0), random.uniform(0, 1/2)))
```

Or, alternatively as a one-liner:

```py
list(map(lambda _: math.sqrt(25/100)-random.uniform(-1/2, 0)**2-random.uniform(0, 1/2), [1]*1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
a=list(map((lambda x,y: math.sqrt((25/100)-(x*x))-y), [random.uniform(-1/2, 0) for i in range(1000)],  [random.uniform(0, 1/2) for i in range(1000)]))
```

For lambda is not friendly to read ,it is not suggested now.